# How can I dispose of an observable after a set time?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

I have an observable that is sending data at a fixed rate every 2 seconds to some observer. I want a way that after 2 minutes has elapsed, the observable that is sending the data will dispose of itself after telling the subject that it completed. I'm using 2 timers one for emitting data for the 2 second intervals and another for the total 2 min duration so it can send the `OnComplete`. I was wondering if there's a way to also dispose itself after the 2 minutes has completed using the timer?

my code looks something like this:

```
Observable.Create<>(
    observer =>
    {
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => observer.OnNext( *send some string* );
        timer.start();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really rather simple. Just do this:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0)))
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
    });
```

This will automatically end the observable after 2 minutes and do all the unsubscribing for you.

Comment: I was looking at [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html). It looks like it doesn't destroy the source Observable unless i'm mistaken? I was hoping there would be a way that would destroy the source observable after the 2 min mark.

Comment: @Armagetin - Yes, it destroys the source observable. Every subscription instantiates the entire pipeline and as soon as the subscription goes so too does the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the help!